# Не перемещает файлы

Tags: python, ос

Имеется вот такой код:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import os
import time
import datetime
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_moved(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
            extension = filename.split('.')
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'jpg' or extension[1].lower() == 'png'):
                file = folder_track + '\\' + filename
                new_path = folder_img + '\\' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)
                print(datetime.datetime.now())
                print('move')
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
            extension = filename.split('.')
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'jpg' or extension[1].lower() == 'png'):
                file = folder_track + '\\' + filename
                new_path = folder_img + '\\' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)
                print(datetime.datetime.now())
                print('move')



folder_track = 'H:\Downoload'
folder_img = 'H:\Downoload\\img'

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(Handler(), folder_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Он должен проверять наличие файлов в папке и в зависимости от формата перемещать их, но при запуске кода ничего не происходит. В пути файла использовал как и одиночный слэш так и двойной, ничего не помогло. Один раз код сработал, но без фильтрации по расширению.

Comment: А каталог у вас точно 'Downoload' называется, а не `Download`?

Comment: Да, копировал прям с пути